# How can I check the bandwidth consumption of any command in Ubuntu?

Tags: 16.04, curl

I would like to know how I can measure the bandwidth consumption of a command in Ubuntu.
For example:
I am running this command on Ubuntu terminal:

```
curl -I trafficinviter.com
```

I get the following result:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Mon, 02 Jan 2017 14:13:14 GMT
Server: Apache
X-Pingback: http://trafficinviter.com/xmlrpc.php
Link: <http://trafficinviter.com/>; rel=shortlink
Set-Cookie: wpfront-notification-bar-landingpage=1
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

But I do not understand how much the bandwidth is consume by the curl command. Even whether the curl has downloaded the complete page and shown me only header? I only want to know whether there is any command that show the bandwidth consumption when I use the curl command as:

```
(some command that show bandwidth consumption) curl -I trafficinviter.com
```

and I get some result like :

```
Bandwidth used: 100kbps
```

Hope this help to define my problem.Kindly let me know your response.

Comment: Try `nethogs`, it monitors network usage per process.

Answer (score 0):

Try health-check, this will tell you how much data has been transferred and how long it ran for, so you can deduce the bitrate from that.  For example, if your userid is 'username', use the following:

```
sudo health-check -u username -f -c -r  curl -I trafficinviter.com
```